# How to show lyrics in music player

Tags: android

I have created a music player ,what should I do to show lyrics in my music player.
Lyrics should be shown according to the playing song.Can anyone please help?.I am developing in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to call a web service that has the lyrics for each song tied to the response.

https://www.musixmatch.com/

There are several APIs you can call within your application to get songs and the lyrics for them. Once you have the response parsed you will just show a TextView that is being passed the response for the lyrics.

Comment: You will need to hit these services online and you can store that data either in SQLite, or something like Sugar ORM, that way you can use the information offline. Also can look into calling your API and using Firebase for offline features. But at first, you will need to hit these services with a networking call to get the data.

Comment: Can you give me link for API other than upper one ?.

Comment: edit my answer with a specific API that gives lyrics from songs.